# use dplyr::mutate() to get rolling mean over selected columns

Tags: r, select, dplyr, rolling-computation

I want to get the rolling means over every last 2 rows in a new column using dplyr. Let's take mtcars as example data.
I will convert the rownames to a new column to better represent my real dataset (which has dates in the first column)

```
df = tibble::rownames_to_column(mtcars, "exclude")
```

Now I want a new column which gives the rolling mean of every last 2 rows (lets assume the "exclude" column which now contains carnames actually contains dates). The should be the output:

[image: df]

I tried to do this with dplyr::mutate() and across() but I haven't managed to do so.

More importantly, at times I may have to compute these rolling rowmeans for previous many rows say 13 or so.

Thanks and best wishes!

Comment: rolling_mean of which column?

Comment: over the rows (i.e. the outcome is in the picture under "new column)

Answer (score 2):

You could take row-wise mean of all the columns excluding the first one and add rolling mean of two values as new column. In base R, you could do :

```
val <- rowMeans(df[-1])
df$new_column <- c(NA, (head(val, -1) + tail(val, -1))/2)
```

If you want to use `dplyr` you can use :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(new_column = rowMeans(.[-1]), 
         new_column = (new_column + lag(new_column))/2)


#              exclude  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb new_column
#1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4         NA
#2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4       29.9
#3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.32 18.6  1  1    4    1       26.8
#4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1       31.2
#5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.44 17.0  0  0    3    2       46.2
#6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.46 20.2  1  0    3    1       44.4
#7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.57 15.8  0  0    3    4       47.4
#8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.19 20.0  1  0    4    2       42.2
#...
#...
```

---

It would be easier if you get the data in long format for a solution to look back `x` number of days.

```
x <- 2
df %>% mutate(row = row_number()) -> df1

df1 %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = -c(exclude, row)) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(val = mean(value)) %>%
  mutate(val = zoo::rollmeanr(val, x, fill = NA)) %>%
  left_join(df1, by = 'row')
```

Comment: I like your second answer. But what if we want the rolling mean over the last 13 days for example. I tried: mutate(new_column= rollapply(.[-1],13,mean,partial=FALSE,fill=NA,align="right")) which works but gives a list as outcome instead of a vector

Comment: I tried something similar as what you do ehen you first exclude the rownumbers and later join them, however I generally don't like to code in such way but prefer to do everything within one dataframe

Answer (score -1):

using `dplyr` you can do

```
df$new <- df %>% mutate(id1 = row_number()) %>% left_join(df %>% mutate(id1 = row_number()+1), by = "id1") %>% 
  select(-exclude.y, -exclude.x, -id1) %>%
  rowMeans()

> df
               exclude  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      new
1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       NA
2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 29.94432
3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 26.78977
4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 31.16886
5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 46.20205
6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 44.35682
7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4 47.38455
8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2 42.17727
9             Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2 25.93409
10            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4 29.54682
11           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4 31.82364
12          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3 39.10909
13          Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 46.46545
14         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 46.42500
15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 56.29136
16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 66.14564
17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 66.01541
18            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 42.70659
19         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 18.59159
20      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 18.27818
21       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 21.85136
22    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 36.06477
23         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 46.62432
24          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 52.38023
25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 58.06614
26           Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 38.15409
27       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 21.85386
28        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 24.82968
29      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 42.92605
30        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 47.74000
31       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 48.83182
32          Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 44.70909
```

for `param` a sufficiently large number

```
library(zoo)
df$new <- df %>% select(-exclude) %>% rowMeans()
param <- 13
df$new <- rollmeanr(df$new, param, fill=NA)


> df
               exclude  mpg cyl  disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb      new
1            Mazda RX4 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4       NA
2        Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4       NA
3           Datsun 710 22.8   4 108.0  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1       NA
4       Hornet 4 Drive 21.4   6 258.0 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1       NA
5    Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8 360.0 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2       NA
6              Valiant 18.1   6 225.0 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1       NA
7           Duster 360 14.3   8 360.0 245 3.21 3.570 15.84  0  0    3    4       NA
8            Merc 240D 24.4   4 146.7  62 3.69 3.190 20.00  1  0    4    2       NA
9             Merc 230 22.8   4 140.8  95 3.92 3.150 22.90  1  0    4    2       NA
10            Merc 280 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.30  1  0    4    4       NA
11           Merc 280C 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.440 18.90  1  0    4    4       NA
12          Merc 450SE 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.070 17.40  0  0    3    3       NA
13          Merc 450SL 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.730 17.60  0  0    3    3 36.85434
14         Merc 450SLC 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.780 18.00  0  0    3    3 38.11916
15  Cadillac Fleetwood 10.4   8 472.0 205 2.93 5.250 17.98  0  0    3    4 40.90773
16 Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215 3.00 5.424 17.82  0  0    3    4 44.17391
17   Chrysler Imperial 14.7   8 440.0 230 3.23 5.345 17.42  0  0    3    4 46.26873
18            Fiat 128 32.4   4  78.7  66 4.08 2.200 19.47  1  1    4    1 43.63615
19         Honda Civic 30.4   4  75.7  52 4.93 1.615 18.52  1  1    4    2 42.30485
20      Toyota Corolla 33.9   4  71.1  65 4.22 1.835 19.90  1  1    4    1 39.15824
21       Toyota Corona 21.5   4 120.1  97 3.70 2.465 20.01  1  0    3    1 39.17779
22    Dodge Challenger 15.5   8 318.0 150 2.76 3.520 16.87  0  0    3    2 40.71681
23         AMC Javelin 15.2   8 304.0 150 3.15 3.435 17.30  0  0    3    2 41.80510
24          Camaro Z28 13.3   8 350.0 245 3.73 3.840 15.41  0  0    3    4 43.87936
25    Pontiac Firebird 19.2   8 400.0 175 3.08 3.845 17.05  0  0    3    2 44.72157
26           Fiat X1-9 27.3   4  79.0  66 4.08 1.935 18.90  1  1    4    1 42.60069
27       Porsche 914-2 26.0   4 120.3  91 4.43 2.140 16.70  0  1    5    2 40.94139
28        Lotus Europa 30.4   4  95.1 113 3.77 1.513 16.90  1  1    5    2 37.76043
29      Ford Pantera L 15.8   8 351.0 264 4.22 3.170 14.50  0  1    5    4 37.36915
30        Ferrari Dino 19.7   6 145.0 175 3.62 2.770 15.50  0  1    5    6 34.94883
31       Maserati Bora 15.0   8 301.0 335 3.54 3.570 14.60  0  1    5    8 38.31149
32          Volvo 142E 21.4   4 121.0 109 4.11 2.780 18.60  1  1    4    2 38.96691
```

The second solution is based on assumption that you don't have any `NA` in any of the rows.  Let's check on a simple data

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = LETTERS,
                 col2 = 1,
                 col3 = 1:26,
                 col4 = 2:27)
df[2,2] <- NA

df
> df
   col1 col2 col3 col4
1     A    1    1    2
2     B   NA    2    3
3     C    1    3    4
4     D    1    4    5
5     E    1    5    6
6     F    1    6    7
7     G    1    7    8
8     H    1    8    9
9     I    1    9   10
10    J    1   10   11
11    K    1   11   12
12    L    1   12   13
13    M    1   13   14
14    N    1   14   15
15    O    1   15   16
16    P    1   16   17
17    Q    1   17   18
18    R    1   18   19
19    S    1   19   20
20    T    1   20   21
21    U    1   21   22
22    V    1   22   23
23    W    1   23   24
24    X    1   24   25
25    Y    1   25   26
26    Z    1   26   27
```

Now the calculation part

```
df$new <- df %>% select(-col1) %>% rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE)
param <- 2
df$new <- rollmeanr(df$new, param, fill=NA)

   col1 col2 col3 col4       new
1     A    1    1    2        NA
2     B   NA    2    3  1.916667
3     C    1    3    4  2.583333
4     D    1    4    5  3.000000
5     E    1    5    6  3.666667
6     F    1    6    7  4.333333
7     G    1    7    8  5.000000
8     H    1    8    9  5.666667
9     I    1    9   10  6.333333
10    J    1   10   11  7.000000
11    K    1   11   12  7.666667
12    L    1   12   13  8.333333
13    M    1   13   14  9.000000
14    N    1   14   15  9.666667
15    O    1   15   16 10.333333
16    P    1   16   17 11.000000
17    Q    1   17   18 11.666667
18    R    1   18   19 12.333333
19    S    1   19   20 13.000000
20    T    1   20   21 13.666667
21    U    1   21   22 14.333333
22    V    1   22   23 15.000000
23    W    1   23   24 15.666667
24    X    1   24   25 16.333333
25    Y    1   25   26 17.000000
26    Z    1   26   27 17.666667
```

Now check it for second row.  It is [(1+1+2)/3 + (2+3)/2]/2 = 1.916 whereas it should be 1+1+2+2+3/5 = 1.800.  Same goes for Ronak's answer.  Now it depends on what you want actually.  Leave a comment if you want it calculate the second way which is mathematically correct.

Comment: but what if we want a 13 day rolling window? changing the "+1" to "
+13" seems incorrect right?

Comment: I mean now we do a 2 row rolling mean but what if we want to change the window for the rolling mean to 13. how should we then apply this in your code?

Comment: But @JelleJansen, this rolling computation (both this one and that proposed by Ronak) is based on mean of means and hence may not give desired results if any of the row element is `NA` anywhere.  In that case a different strategy will have to be adopted.  Try this code after `df[2,5] <- NA` and check.  That's why I proposed earlier the problem with join.

Comment: so it seems we don't have a suited solution yet if I read it correctly. I use rollapply in other examples within dplyr which does the trick. It's just a pitty I don't know how to leave out the first column when using rollapply within mutate() in a wide format dataframe

Comment: No.  It depends on what results are expected.  If you want actual means (and not mean of means) you can use count non NA/null values and alongside use rowSums.  Thereafter you can combine rowSums and count to calculate actual mean

Answer (score -1):

In the end I converted it to xts format so I can use rollapply over the dataset without having to worry about the datecolumn.